# How to get value of dynamic id in an html loop with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a drag and drop system using redips javascript.

This is my script using html and php to generate the data

```
<div id="base">  
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <?php 
          foreach($deviceID as $row)
          { 
             echo '<tr><td><div class="drag">'.$row['description'].'<input type="hidden" id="bus" value="'.$row['description'].'"></div></td></tr>'; 
          }
        ?>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the fragment of my javascript file.

```
var redips_init;
redips_init = function () {
    // reference to the REDIPS.drag
    var rd = REDIPS.drag;
    // initialization
    rd.init();
        rd.drop_option = 'shift';
    rd.animation_shift = true;

        rd.myhandler_dropped = function () {            
            alert($('#bus').val());
        }
};
```

Comment: how can it be dynamic when all inputs have `bus` as an ID? IDs can only be used once.

Comment: The markup resulting from your PHP will be invalid unless you only have one row (but then, why would you have a loop). `id` values **must** be [unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: The posted PHP code is going to result in non-unique element IDs.  IDs are, by definition, supposed to be unique.  You need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good with php but what i usually do in jsp is create a local index variable and append it to each of the ID attribute in the loop.

So your code would look something like this

```
  <?php 
      $index=0;    
      foreach($deviceID as $row)
          { 
             echo '<tr><td><div class="drag">'.$row['description'].'<input type="hidden" id="bus'.$index++.'" value="'.$row['description'].'"></div></td></tr>'; 
          }
        ?>
```

In javascript, your dragAndDrop event should return an index location by which u can get appropriate value.

Now you can use this dynamic ID in your JavaScript to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: I tried it like that but the problem is how do I get the id of that element in javascript? Because I am only dragging one element at a time, How do I know which id that the element have?

Comment: hmmm...not completely sure abt the redips library..checkout the third table example on this link http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/    .You will need to see the code how they determine the index on drag event

Answer (score 0):

REDIPS.drag contains [save_content()](http://www.redips.net/javascript/redips-drag-documentation/#save_content) method to scan all DIV elements in a table and to return the result as **Query string** or **JSON** object. Input parameters are table id and type of returned result (default is query string). If this is not good enough, you can search for save_content() source and make customization. Method is simple and it uses several loops to scan table content.

On the other hand, if you need to know ID of dropped DIV element that can be written inside **myhandler_dropped** event hander. Here is code snippet:

```
rd.myhandler_dropped = function () {
    // define DIV id
    var id = rd.obj.id;
    // write DIV id to the console
    console.log(id)
};
```

Hope this answer will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but I already solved all of the problems I had in regards to redips. I did it the way you code it. Thanks anyway. Cool js! It helped me a lot! :D